# How to find the largest number of a table

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, I have to find the names of all the ships whose number of guns was the largest for those ships of the same bore. The ship name is in the ships table and the number of guns and bore size is in the classes table.

```
Create Table Classes (
    class Varchar(40),
    type Char (2),
    country Varchar(15),
    numGuns Int,
    bore Int,
    displacement Int
);
Create Table Ships (
    name Varchar(40),
    class Varchar(40),
    launched Int
);
```

One thing I've been thinking of doing is joining ships with classes and then using a correlated subquery. I've tried doing that but nothing I do seems to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
Select DISTINCT name
From Classes T1, Classes T2, Ships
Where T1.bore = T2.bore AND T1.numGuns = 
    (Select MAX(X.numGuns)
    From Classes X, Classes Y
    Where X.bore = Y.bore);
```

Yet the result gives me too many ships so what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your data set, different approaches may yield different performance and cost profiles.

After loading a little data(my boat knowledge is lacking in these examples) where canoes and rowboats are tied with more guns than clippers, but the same bore, and Catamarans have more guns than IronClads but the same bore:

```
INSERT INTO CLASSES VALUES('Clipper','CT','UK',7,3,3);
INSERT INTO CLASSES VALUES('Canoe','CO','JP',19,3,9);
INSERT INTO CLASSES VALUES('Rowboat','CO','KO',19,3,95);
INSERT INTO CLASSES VALUES('IronClad','IC','MG',3,11,4);
INSERT INTO CLASSES VALUES('Catamaran','CA','FR',9,11,6);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('Cutty Sark','Clipper',9);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('HMS Canoe','Canoe',11);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('SS Boat','Rowboat',77);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('USS Boat','Canoe',33);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('Dreadnought','IronClad',12);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('Boaty','Catamaran',19);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES ('McBoatFace','Catamaran',23);
COMMIT;
```

There are multiple approaches to this kind of query.  I'll outline some examples that use inline views, but other patterns would also work.

One question I'd have in looking at this data is how you'd like to handle the occurrence of a tie between two classes with the same number of guns and the same bore.
If you want to be sure that only one `CLASS` is included per `BORE` (if you want to break ties) then aggregating with a `KEEP` clause may work.  Please note this will force-out any case where there are ties.
The below will find the `CLASS` for each `BORE` that has the most `GUNS`, and fetch all `SHIPS` of that `CLASS`.  (If I'm understanding the intended query correctly)

```
SELECT BORE_MAX_GUN.BORE, BORE_MAX_GUN.MAX_GUN_CLASS,  SHIPS.NAME 
FROM SHIPS
INNER JOIN (SELECT BORE, 
MAX(CLASS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY NUMGUNS ASC) AS MAX_GUN_CLASS 
FROM CLASSES GROUP BY BORE) BORE_MAX_GUN
ON SHIPS.CLASS = BORE_MAX_GUN.MAX_GUN_CLASS
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC;
```

Returns:

```
BORE  MAX_GUN_CLASS  NAME
3     Rowboat        SS Boat
11    Catamaran      Boaty
11    Catamaran      McBoatFace
```

In this data, Catamarans have more guns than IronClads and Canoes/Rowboats have more than Clippers.  The tie between Canoe and Rowboat is resolved alphabetically, and all the Ships of the Class with the most Guns for each Bore are returned.

If you'd like to keep ties on the number of guns, you can use analytic functions instead:

```
SELECT 
BORE_MAX_GUN.BORE,
BORE_MAX_GUN.CLASS,  SHIPS.NAME 
FROM SHIPS
INNER JOIN
(SELECT BORE,
CLASS,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BORE ORDER BY NUMGUNS DESC) AS GUN_RANK
FROM CLASSES)  BORE_MAX_GUN
ON SHIPS.CLASS = BORE_MAX_GUN.CLASS
AND BORE_MAX_GUN.GUN_RANK = 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC;
```

Returns:

```
BORE  CLASS      NAME
3     Canoe      HMS Canoe
3     Canoe      USS Boat
3     Rowboat    SS Boat
11    Catamaran  Boaty
11    Catamaran  McBoatFace
```

The above will fetch all classes, including ties, that have the most guns for their bore size, and return all the ships of each class.  In this data set, both the Canoes and Rowboats are included, but the Clippers are not.

Performance may differ between approaches so benchmarking is recommended, but hopefully these may be a starting place.